# Angular2 APP Init[i] error when ng serve is used

Tags: angular

```
NG-CLi - 1.0.0-beta.28.3
Angular2 : 2.4.6
```

here is my function in app.module.ts

```
 export function authFactory(auth : LoginService){
  return auth.loginUser();
}
```

Providers are reference like this

```
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  //useFactory: (auth: AuthService) => () => auth.authUser(),
  useFactory : authFactory,
  deps: [LoginService],
  multi: true
}
```

This was running until we upgraded `angular cli` and `Angular 2` to `2.4.6` from `2.1.0`. Also cli version we upgraded from `beta 18` to `28`.

Now when app starts it is giving this error in console, i do see that request is working fine in the loginUser method. But somehow it is giving error about promise used in the http post request

> Unhandled Promise rejection: appInits[i] is not a function ; Zone:
>    ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: appInits[i] is not a
>   function

Comment: I've the same issue

Comment: This example may work - https://dormoshe.io/articles/hook-into-angular-initialization-process-8

Answer (score 2):

This error ( at least in my case ) happens when the factory function used returns **undefined**.

In my case I was wrongly translating:

```
useFactory: () => () => {}
```

to

```
useFactory: noop,
export function noop() {}
```

and solve it changing it from:

```
export function noop(){}
```

to

```
export function noop() {
   return () => {};
}
```

... and the reason why a factory is an empty function is because I have some entities that should be available in the DIC without any entity injecting them explicitly